# Layout run failed when adding `locked:true` to `actionColumn`

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I need a action column to be locked in postion and size. Therefore I thought is the `locked` property but as soon as I add it I get the

> [E] Layout run failed

error for each row to render. What do I wrong or is this a bug?

I am using ExtJS 4.2.1

```
{
    layout: 'hbox',
    border: false,
    xtype: 'container',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'grid',
            shrinkWrapDock: true,
            flex: 1,
            store: store,
            minHeight: 300,
            title: 'Test',
            columns: [
                { xtype:'actioncolumn', locked: true, sortable: false, hideable: false, dataIndex: 'Aktiv', width: 20, items: [{
                        tooltip: 'deactivate', 
                        handler: function(view,row,col,item,ev,rec,row) {
                            rec.data.set('Active',!rec.data.get('Active'));
                        } 
                    }]
                },
                // more columns
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you show your codes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure why you are getting that error, but I don't think `locked` is what you are looking for.

If you are trying to prevent the user from changing the column width and from dragging the column into a new position, then try adding the following instead of `locked`:

```
draggable: false,
resizable: false
```

Edit:

You also mentioned you wanted to restrict the user from hiding the column. Do this by adding the following config to the two listed above:

```
hideable: false
```

And check out the documentation for more config options and information.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will give it a try! (I had already given up to find a solution) Can you clarify for what should I use locked then? Note that the column must not be hidden by any user!

Comment: Ok, that worked for me even if it is not a answer while the layout Fails. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have experience using locked columns, so I'm not sure what scenery you would use them in. However, here is an example of one made with ExtJS 4. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/locking-grid.html

Comment: Also, if you want to restrict the user from hiding the column, as you mentioned in your comment above, you would want to add `hideable: false` to the column. Check out the documentation for more config options. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column